# Waiting for window / global variable to be defined in a Jest test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
// index.html
// this script defines window.externalLibrary variable to use throughout app, 
// it just takes a second or few to load as "window.externalLibrary" is always undefined on startup
<script src="https://www.something.com/externalLibrary.js"></script>

// package.json
jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/jest/globals.js"
    ]

// globals.js
global.externalLibrary = window.externalLibrary;

// externalLibraryTest.js
describe('externalLibrary.js Tests', () => {
  it('Please work', () => {
    console.log(window.externalLibrary);  //undefined
    console.log(global.externalLibrary); //undefined too
  });
```

How can I get this to work?

Usually in my app I use a function on load before using the variable:

```
export const initializeExternalLibrary = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (window.singularApp) resolve(window.singularApp);
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'singularApp', {
      set (value) {
        console.log('External Library Initialized.');
        resolve(value);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

but I tried using that function inside the Jest test and that didn't work as well.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm a bit desperate, thank you

Comment: Why are you testing third-party libraries inside your app? Or am I misreading this?

Comment: you're not mis-reading it i don't think?  i'm using this 3rd party library to create helper functions and i would like to test the helper functions I've created

Comment: You could mock what the library does and then just test that your functions call the library appropriately.

Comment: @Baruch I wish I could but it's a proprietary library that returns objects and info that isn't mockable or else I definitely would do that.  thanks though